# Migration and Tables assigned in AppServiceProviders

Tags: laravel, migration

Im trying to solve this problem with larave...

i have this AppServiceProvider.php file:

```
public function boot()
    {
        /*if( (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] !== 'off') || $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443) {
            URL::forceScheme('https');
        }*/
        //setting language
        if(isset($_COOKIE['language'])) {
            \App::setLocale($_COOKIE['language']);
        } else {
            \App::setLocale('en');
        }
        //get general setting value        
        $general_setting = DB::table('general_settings')->latest()->first();
        $currency = \App\Models\Currency::find($general_setting->currency);
        View::share('general_setting', $general_setting);
        View::share('currency', $currency);
        config(['staff_access' => $general_setting->staff_access, 'date_format' => $general_setting->date_format, 'currency' => $currency->code, 'currency_position' => $general_setting->currency_position]);
        
        $alert_product = DB::table('products')->where('is_active', true)->whereColumn('alert_quantity', '>', 'qty')->count();
        View::share('alert_product', $alert_product);
        Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
    }
```

all my system work perfectly... but i need run php artisan migrate or migrate:fresh... to make a new installation... and it show:

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'testsystem.general_settings' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `general_settings` order by `created_at` desc limit 1)

  at D:\WebServer74\htdocs\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:678
    674▕         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    675▕         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    676▕         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    677▕         catch (Exception $e) {
  ➜ 678▕             throw new QueryException(
    679▕                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    680▕             );
    681▕         }
    682▕
```

My system work correctly and need the code in AppServiceProvider to work, but at same time if i need run a fresh migration... (for multi tenant purpose) i cant make migration...

any can help me please?

Answer (score 0):

Would try this ?

```
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        // ...
        if (!app()->runningInConsole() || app()->runningUnitTests()) {
            $general_setting = DB::table('general_settings')->latest()->first();
            //...
        }
    }
}
```